# Structuring the Details of a C++ Class in Debug

Tags: c++, class, debugging, cross-platform, c++17

How does one enhance the debug information shown for a C++ Class? Specifically, let's look at the `vector` class: its top level view only contains its size variable *(#1 in image)* and the expanded view shows its elements one-by-one as parameters so to speak *(#2 in image)*.

**How does one control what's being shown in the top-level summary, and what's being shown in the sub-level? Are there certain design patterns that achieve this?**

**Edit: Is there a cross-platform solution? One that works for CLion under Linux, VS on Win, CMake in general, etc.**

A small working example that replicates the vector behaviour would be incredibly useful (if that's even possible without having to replicate the complex nature of the actual vector class).

[image: screenshot]

---

Say, I attempt to write a class as follows

```
template <class T> class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(size_t size) : size(size)
    {
        buffer = new T[size];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            buffer[i] = T();
    }

    ~Vector()
    {
        if (buffer != NULL)
            delete[]buffer;
    }

    T operator[](const size_t& idx) { /* ... */ }

private:
    size_t size;
    T* buffer;
};
```

then the debugger only shows me this (as one would expect looking at the structure of the class):
[image]

Comment: Note that CMake is not an IDE but a build system. It cannot visualize variables at all, so natvis support does not even make sense.

Comment: @MSalters Understood, but my question is, how would I include a *natvis* file (or other) into a CMake project so that when I open my CMake project in either VS or CLion (or another IDE) I get the same debug view on my classes. Or will I have to include the debug formats for each IDE separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Natvis visualization.  The details are too long to go in to here, but see the Microsoft documentation for how to [Create custom views of native objects in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2017) for how to create them.

Comment: Thanks! How portable is this approach? If I include a natvis file for me class to work with VS on Win, will CLion on Linux be able to pick this up too?

Comment: I think your link goes to the parent page, and you wanted to link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2017 instead.

Comment: @MSalters I did want the other link.  I originally copied the parent page, saw the next page was better, and apparently didn't copy that link when I though I did.  Link fixed in the answer.